# How to retrieve email address from id_token Google Javascript API client (GAPI)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api-js-client, google-identity

I have an SPA with Firebase backend and have integrated Google Calendar access.

To be able to authorise a user to use his/her Google Calendar I am using the `gapi.auth2.authorize(params, callback)` method. *(this as opposed to the regular `gapi.auth2.init` and `signIn` flow because my users can link multiple Calendar accounts)*

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauth2authorizeparams-callback): `gapi.auth2.authorize`

#### The problem I am experiencing:

Sometimes the `id_token` that is returned from `authorize` includes an email address, and sometimes it doesn't.

The id_token which is returned is a long string that can be read on the front end with a JavaScript function like so:

```javascript
    function parseJwt (token) {
      let base64Url = token.split('.')[1]
      let base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/')
      return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64))
    }
```

When I parse the id_token, I am expecting an object including an `email` address. However sometimes it doesn't include the `email` property at all....
How can I retrieve the user's google calendar email address from this id_token in with JavaScript, so I can save it to the user's firestore DB?

#### Example of an expected result when parsing the id_token:

[image: expected result]

#### Example of an un-expected result (no email):

[image: unexpected result]

#### Possible cause:

I think that it might be related to the accounts not returning an email being a Google G-Suite account? And the ones that do return the email is a regular gmail account? But I don't know the solution.

PS:
My flow for re-authorisation for return users is to just use the same `gapi.auth2.authorize` but with `{prompt: 'none', login_hint: 'emailaddress'}` and fill in the user's saved email address. This works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to authorise the JavaScript client with `gapi.auth2.authorize` but also require the email address the user authorised for, **be sure to include `email` in the scope** of the `gapi.auth2.authorize(params, callback)` parameters!!

#### A correct example of using JavaScript gapi for authorisation of Google calendar:

Step 1.
 Include in main HTML head:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" async defer=defer></script>
```

Step 2.
 (once) Load the client:
 `window.gapi.load('client', callbackFunction)`
**Important: Only load the client!**

Step 3.
 (once) Initialise the client for usage of Calendar API.
**Important: Only include the discovery docs!**

```
let calDocs = {
    discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest']
}
window.gapi.client.init(calDocs)
    .then(_ => {
      console.log('Calendar client initialised')
    })
  })
},
```

Step 4.
 (once) Authorise the gapi client for API calls with
 `gapi.auth2.authorize(params, callbackFunction)`
**Important: Scope is a string with spaces!** Include email in the scope. Do NOT include the discovery docs here!

```
params = {
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar email',
    response_type: 'permission id_token'
}
```

You can repeat the `gapi.auth2.authorize` before any API call with extra params: `{prompt: 'none', login_hint: 'emailaddress'}` to refresh the user's access token. This will not show any prompt to the user if he already authorised once for your domain.